# How to get content of a DOM element without being in the React context

Tags: reactjs

Right now I'm writing a middleware (from Redux) to consume an API and set the fetched data into the state, however, to call the API I need to set the token to get the data, and the token is saved in a field inside a meta tag in the header, like:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="xJ4XRg4YDnxC8WHpdiFh8t5DzOgeCO7UHCfcStgL">
```

As our application started JQuery, I could use the following code to get the value:

```
$('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
```

But I'd like to do that without JQuery, just using React.

What would be the best way to do that?

Comment: Why don't you use pure javascript? 

document.getElementsByTagName("meta")[0].getAttribute('content')

Comment: @ChrisChen I'm just verifying if that is the best way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are outside React class (Component), you can do the following without worry :

```
document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;
```

If you are inside React class (Component) , this snippet is valuable only after mounting (going from [virtual-dom](/questions/tagged/virtual-dom) to [dom](/questions/tagged/dom) ). Thus, you can call it inside the following methods of component:

- `componentDidMount`
- `render`
- `componentDidUpdate`